# how to store this date string in mysql db to allow sorting by date?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, date, datetime

With PHP I am pulling in some data records by XML and the Date field is a string in the following format:

Thu, 19 May 2016 22:58:58 +0900 (JST)

When I save this Date to MySQL table in a VARCHAR column, I am unable to sort by date correctly.  It sorts the strings alphabetically so that all the dates starting with 'Fri' come first, regardless of DD/MM/YYYY value.

So I think I need to:
- change my table structure so the Date field is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME instead of VARCHAR.
- use PHP strtotime() or similar function to convert the string to TIMESTAMP.

But I cant get it working, can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to save in this format. This may helps you.

```
$sortable_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s D',strtotime($your_date))." + 0900 (JST)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should convert your database to use a DateTime column and this is how you can convert these dates to a format that will store into a DateTime column

```
<?php
$in = 'Thu, 19 May 2016 22:58:58 +0900 (JST)';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s P e', $in);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
```

Result =

```
2016-05-19 22:58:58
```